is this any npm which suport gstreamer in node js
my problem is i convert rtsp live video stream in webrtc using gstreamer but can not play it in browser  i don't wont to globally install in my system  is Their any package in npm packages for same as gstreamer for conversion
convrting rtsp live video stream in webrtc using gstreamer and live video stream play in browser
